# clicear una imagen pero que aparezca otra!

Tags: javascript, html, imagen, onclick, click

Quisiera poder cambiar las img del contenedor-img pero que al clicear salga las que ya estaban!! es decir: Imagen x seleccionada pero al clikearla en ves de que salga la x salga otra:Y por ej!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function $(element_id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(element_id);
        }
        function setSrc(element_id, src)
        {
            var element = $(element_id);
            element.src = src;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, agrega tu avance por favor

Comment: No puedo subirlo dice que no admite mi còdigo!1

Comment: Checa [ask], si no te admite el código es por que es demasiado y muy poca explicación, trata de dar mejor contexto de tu duda y solo agregar el código mínimo necesario

Comment: Entonces, ¿quieres que desde el inicio aparezca una imagen pero que al darle click aparezca en su lugar otra?

Comment: el tema es que esta funcion cambia el src de la foto principal y eso esta bien lo que yo quiero es que las fotos secundarias se vean otras en la web pero q al clikearlas salgan otras..

Comment: Es un catalogo de fotos.... hay una foto grande de una camiseta X y luego hay otras fotos màs pequeñas(como muetras) que al clikear en cualkiera de ellas aparece como img principal.... yo quiero que esas fotos màs pequeñas en la web se vean sus escudos pero al clikear cualkiera de ellas aparesca la camiseta...se entendio??

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar clicar sobre las imágenes y recuperar otra imagen específica. Prueba esto:

```
    function cambio1 () { document.getElementById('cambio1').src = 
     "https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg"
    }

    function cambio2 () { document.getElementById('cambio2').src =  "https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h4>Cambio imagenes</h4>

    <img id="cambio1" onclick="cambio1()"  src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Stickman" width="34" height="59">


    <img id="cambio2" onclick="cambio2()" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="32" height="32">

    </body>
    </html>
```